# how to create bins for date time by month and plot value counts on it?

Tags: pandas, plot, bar-chart, histogram

I have 8000 days column of type TimeStamp:

```
2013-09-06 00:00:00
```

I want to create bar plots, but group it by month, maybe later year. right now I have too many values(days) and they all become one black spot on the plot:

```
basic_data['opendate'].value_counts().plot(kind='barh')
```

I tried this:

```
by_month = basic_data['opendate].groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='M')).sum() #maybe count?
```

How to plot and create bins on histogram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) with `key` parameter by `opendate` column and then [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=100)
basic_data = pd.DataFrame({'opendate': rng, 'a': range(100)})  
print (basic_data)
     opendate   a
0  2017-04-03   0
1  2017-04-04   1
2  2017-04-05   2
3  2017-04-06   3
4  2017-04-07   4
..        ...  ..
95 2017-07-07  95
96 2017-07-08  96
97 2017-07-09  97
98 2017-07-10  98
99 2017-07-11  99

[100 rows x 2 columns]

basic_data.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='opendate', freq='M')).size().plot(kind='barh')
```

[image: graph]